# RS256 message too long for RSA public key size - error signing JWT

Tags: go, jwt, rsa, pem, jwt-go

I'm using https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go to build a JWT using a 256-bit private PEM key. I'm using `SigningMethodRS256` to sign the JWT:

```
signBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(privKeyPath)
signKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(signBytes)
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS256, middleware.CognitoAccessTokenClaim{
    CustomArray:  []string{"testString"},
    StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
    ExpiresAt: 1500,
    },
})
jwtString, err := token.SignedString(signKey)
```

On the last line, I get an error when signing the jwt: `crypto/rsa: message too long for RSA public key size`. Does anyone know what causes this? The size of the pem file seems correct.

Comment: 256 bits is a very small key size.  Is there a reason for that? You can solve this just by generating a larger key (2048 or 4096 bits). See https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/issues/213.

Answer (score 4):

You need split message to chunks

```
func EncryptOAEP(hash hash.Hash, random io.Reader, public *rsa.PublicKey, msg []byte, label []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    msgLen := len(msg)
    step := public.Size() - 2*hash.Size() - 2
    var encryptedBytes []byte

    for start := 0; start < msgLen; start += step {
        finish := start + step
        if finish > msgLen {
            finish = msgLen
        }

        encryptedBlockBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(hash, random, public, msg[start:finish], label)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        encryptedBytes = append(encryptedBytes, encryptedBlockBytes...)
    }

    return encryptedBytes, nil
}

func DecryptOAEP(hash hash.Hash, random io.Reader, private *rsa.PrivateKey, msg []byte, label []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    msgLen := len(msg)
    step := private.PublicKey.Size()
    var decryptedBytes []byte

    for start := 0; start < msgLen; start += step {
        finish := start + step
        if finish > msgLen {
            finish = msgLen
        }

        decryptedBlockBytes, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(hash, random, private, msg[start:finish], label)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        decryptedBytes = append(decryptedBytes, decryptedBlockBytes...)
    }

    return decryptedBytes, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you generated your private key is not correct. I resolved the same issue by taking reference from [here](https://gist.github.com/ygotthilf/baa58da5c3dd1f69fae9)

Steps to generate key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f jwtRS256.key
# Don't add passphrase
openssl rsa -in jwtRS256.key -pubout -outform PEM -out jwtRS256.key.pub
cat jwtRS256.key
cat jwtRS256.key.pub
```

Steps to use it using jwt-go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "io/ioutil"
    "time"
)

func panicOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    signBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./jwtRS256.key")
    panicOnError(err)
    signKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(signBytes)
    panicOnError(err)
    verifyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./jwtRS256.key.pub")
    panicOnError(err)
    verifyKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(verifyBytes)
    panicOnError(err)
    claims := jwt.MapClaims{
        "exp": time.Now().Add(time.Minute).Unix(),
    }
    fmt.Println(claims)
    t := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS256, claims)
    tokenString, err := t.SignedString(signKey)
    panicOnError(err)
    fmt.Println(tokenString)
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return verifyKey, nil
    })
    panicOnError(err)
    fmt.Println(token.Claims)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer, to avoid a misunderstanding: `RS256` doesn't require the private key to have a size of mere 256 bits. The `256` in `RS256` describes that the used hashing algorithm is `SHA-256`. Opposed to that, the bit size you're passing on key generation describes the length of the modulus and not related - and should, depending on what you're about to sign, larger than 256 bits. I fell for the same.