# receiving crypto/rsa: decryption error when decrypting a file

Tags: go, encryption

This is my decrypt function but it keeps returning: "crypto/rsa: decryption error". any advice would be helpful! I split the encryption into sections because the key kept raising the "key too short error". I am new to the encryption work in golang.

```
func DecryptFile(file string, privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey)([]byte, error){
  var decryptedBytes []byte
  // read the file into bytes
  data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
  if err != nil {
    return decryptedBytes,err
  }
  fmt.Println(len(data))
  var decryptedByte []byte
  ByteSlice := split(data,200)
  rng := rand.Reader
  for _,bytes := range ByteSlice{
    decryptedBytes,err = rsa.DecryptOAEP(
      sha256.New(),
      rng,
      privateKey,
      bytes,
      nil)
    if err != nil {
     return decryptedBytes,err
    }
    decryptedBytes = append(decryptedBytes,decryptedByte...)
  }

  return decryptedBytes,nil
}
```

Encryption function:

```
func EncryptFile(file string, PublicKey *rsa.PublicKey)([]byte, error){
  var encryptedBytes []byte

  // read the file into bytes
  data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
  if err != nil {
    return encryptedBytes,err
  }
  fmt.Println(len(data))
  // Encrypts the file
  //fmt.Println(PublicKey.N.BitLen())
  //_,_ = strconv.Atoi((PublicKey.N).String())
  ByteSlice := split(data,200)
  var encryptedByte []byte
  rng := rand.Reader
  for _,bytes := range ByteSlice{
    encryptedByte, err = rsa.EncryptOAEP(
         sha256.New(),
         rng,
         PublicKey,
         bytes,
         nil)
    if err != nil {
      return encryptedBytes,err
    }
    encryptedBytes = append(encryptedBytes, encryptedByte...)
  }

  // Returns file encrypted
  return encryptedBytes,nil
}
```

Comment: Do not split the input.

Comment: I tried doing that but it returns the same error. I'll add the encryption function as well.

Comment: what is ur split function and how did you generate private/public key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? (don't mind the language difference) https://stackoverflow.com/a/35686847/1816580

Comment: It would be better to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) instead of RSA in ECB mode. This is faster and less error prone

Comment: Take a look at the size of your encrypted data vs the data in clear. Notice that it have grown in size. You don't account for this in your decrypt, but instead just assume the blocks are 200 bytes ... RSA is not suited for bulk encryption

Comment: How would I calculate the block size after encryption?

Answer (score 1):

The step for `rsa.EncryptOAEP()` should be no longer than :

```
publicKey.Size() - 2*hash.Size() - 2
```

You can use `publicKey.Size() - 2*hash.Size() - 2` as step of  `rsa.EncryptOAEP()`

No matter the length of step,
`rsa.EncryptOAEP()` function always produce fixed length encrypted data, the fixed length is `publicKey.Size()`.

so, the step for `rsa.DecryptOAEP()` is :

```
publicKey.Size()
```

Please see :
[RS256 message too long for RSA public key size - error signing JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348923/rs256-message-too-long-for-rsa-public-key-size-error-signing-jwt?answertab=votes#tab-top)